# How to Access to Laravel 5 with Pingpong-Modules to a specific Module

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel 5 and Pingpong-Modules https://github.com/pingpong-labs/modules

I want to Access from an outsite of the Modules-Directory to a Specific Module-Function.

My Actual Configuration is:

I want to access to the Method "test()" from the DashboardController - what is here the best practice?

Code of Controller 1:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\AdminController;
use App\News;
use App\NewsCategory;
use App\User;
use App\Video;
use App\VideoAlbum;
use App\Photo;
use App\PhotoAlbum;

use \Pingpong\Modules\Facades\Module;
use App\Helpers\ModulesHelper;


class DashboardController extends AdminController {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $title = "Dashboard";

        $news = News::count();
        $newscategory = NewsCategory::count();
        $users = User::count();
        $photo = Photo::count();
        $photoalbum = PhotoAlbum::count();
        $video = Video::count();
        $videoalbum = VideoAlbum::count();


        return view('admin.dashboard.index',  compact('title','news','newscategory','video','videoalbum','photo',
            'photoalbum','users'));
    }
```

Code of Controller 2:

```
<?php namespace Modules\Users\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class UsersController extends Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        return View::make('users::index');
    }

    public function test() {
        return "TEST";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this block wherever you want in DashboardController:

```
$usersController = App::make('Modules\Users\Http\Controllers\UsersController');
$usersController->test();
```